# Resumable Upload File by Forge SDK, UploadChunkWithHttpInfo failing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to upload a file using the SDK for .Net, using this sample:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/c-resumable-upload-file-forge-sdk

If I use REST API directly, I can create bucket and upload files without problems, using direct upload without chunks.
If I use the SDK method, I always get

```
Message: "An error has occurred."
ExceptionMessage: "Error calling UploadChunk: {"developerMessage":"ACM check failed, user or calling service does not have access to perform this operation","userMessage":"","errorCode":"AUTH-012","more info":"http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/AUTH-012"}"
ExceptionType: "Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException"
StackTrace: "   at Autodesk.Forge.ObjectsApi.UploadChunkWithHttpInfo(String bucketKey, String objectName, Nullable`1 contentLength, String contentRange, String sessionId, Stream body, String contentDisposition, String ifMatch)
```

I have verified that the bucket keys are the same.
I am using 1.4.0 version of SDK, there is a 1.5.1 Alpha version available which I would prefer not to use.

Comment: That error suggests your bucket key is incorrect. Did you encode it before passing to the call? No need to do that coz the SDK takes care of that for you.

Comment: No the key is correct, it works when using REST calls, not SDK. I get the exact same error if I use non-chunk upload, i.e. ObjectsApi.UploadObject.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried [this code](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bucket.manager-csharp-sample.tool/blob/master/bucket.manager/Form1.cs#L187) with the `HttpInfo` option, as seen below, and worked fine. From your message, and as pointed out by @Bryan Huang, the error is most likely related to authentication (or a temp glitch)

```
long chunkSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 Mb
long numberOfChunks = (long)Math.Round((double)(fileSize / chunkSize)) + 1;

progressBar.Maximum = (int)numberOfChunks;

long start = 0;
chunkSize = (numberOfChunks > 1 ? chunkSize : fileSize);
long end = chunkSize;
string sessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

// upload one chunk at a time
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)))
{
    for (int chunkIndex = 0; chunkIndex < numberOfChunks; chunkIndex++)
    {
        string range = string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", start, end, fileSize);

        long numberOfBytes = chunkSize + 1;
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[numberOfBytes];
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
        reader.BaseStream.Seek((int)start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        int count = reader.Read(fileBytes, 0, (int)numberOfBytes);
        memoryStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, (int)numberOfBytes);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        dynamic chunkUploadResponse = await objects.UploadChunkAsyncWithHttpInfo(bucketKey, objectKey, (int)numberOfBytes, range, sessionId, memoryStream);

        start = end + 1;
        chunkSize = ((start + chunkSize > fileSize) ? fileSize - start - 1 : chunkSize);
        end = start + chunkSize;

        progressBar.CustomText = string.Format("{0} Mb uploaded...", (chunkIndex * chunkSize) / 1024 / 1024);
        progressBar.Value = chunkIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see from your sample that you use two-legged authentication. I use three-legged and A360, so maybe this SDK call only works with two-legged authentication and BIM360?
I noticed when I tried som other bucket methods that they failed, and describing that they only worked with 2-legged auth.

Comment: Got the same error on BIM360, but still using 3-legged auth which is not required in this case

Comment: I’ll check that

Comment: Augusto: I have basen my code on your sample code in the article at
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/upload-files-bim-360-c,
and the file upload that your refer to in
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/c-resumable-upload-file-forge-sdk.
Your article says it is for BIM360, so I have now changed my code to use two-legged authentication and BIM360.
Your code is using projectApi.PostStorageAsync and retrieves the bucketKey from the response.  In my code, 
"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/40e0e6c5-bd92-4d49-90e6-82ea9b083bbe.jpg", and your code extracts "wip.dm.prod" as the bucketKey.

Comment: This bucketKey works in REST API, but not SDK!! If I iterate BucketsAPI.GetBuckets, my bucketKey is bjv1ueyw3aaaxjsxkiaxsmnzoxjefykn636755378203905689, i.e. totally different format!
And this key works in the ObjectsApi! Problem is, how do I ensure they are the same?
So far I find the SDK far more complicated and frustrating to use, luckily I have working code using REST API only

Comment: Well, BucketsAPI can only use two-legged tokens, so it cannot be used with A360. And you can only use the bucketKey from bucketsAPI, so I guess you cannot use ObjectsApi either...
The blog articles should clarify that they only works with BIM 360, and you should correct yours since the bucketKey you extract is not working with the article you link to